# How to run GitLab on a dyndns?

Tags: installation, gitlab

I want to install and run GitLab on my RaspberryPi3. I have two problems: it runs on a NO-o-IP Address (example.ddns.net) on a specific, not custom port (80880 for example).

I installed gitlab and reconfigured it like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
$ sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
$ sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

In that file I changed the external_url from 'http://raspberrypi' to 'http://example.ddns.net:80880/gitlab'. I added '/gitlab' because I have a normal webserver running.

When I go to http://example.ddns.net:80880/gitlab , I get a 404 page not found error.

How can I configure this correctly?

Comment: Port numbers cannot exceed 65535, so 80880 is out of range.

Comment: @Marcolz It was just an example port. Choose 6665 or 6541 or 8888 or 1002 or whatever you want... I use another port, but that's a port that's always open and I would ike to prevent everyone of logging in to my machine...

Comment: You have to have IP address of RaspberryPi3 connected to your http://example.ddns.net:80880/gitlab, so this domain lead to your RaspberryPi3

Comment: @Saz So what should I do with that IP address? That changes every night...

Comment: will it work for you ? https://www.noip.com/download?page=win

Comment: @Saz That is installed on the RPi3 itself. So I forwarded internally port 80880 (as example) to port 80 on the raspberry pi. So what should I do now? Everything of No-IP is configured and the ports are forwarded.how can I make that my website on the pi is reachable on example.ddns.net:80880 and gitlab server on example.ddns.net:80880/gitlab ?

Comment: Let's debug! Can you ping\connect using your IP ( not noip domain ) ? If you can't you must be double check forwarding and your firewalls. Try to connect to RPi from your local network (if you can't check if you run and setup gitlab correctly)

Comment: @Saz No, I get forwarded to Apache2 test page. Internally and externally too.

Comment: GitLab comes with it's own nginx webserver, i guess, you need to set up gitlab to use it with apache (or you can try use gitlab on different port from apache ). check this guide https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server